# Big O of the fastest algo to print the common elements between an unsorted array of length n and sorted array of length m

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, big-o

My thinking is that it would take O(n*m)
This is because

1 2 3 4

4 3 2 1

In order to find the common elements, you would iterate through the sorted array and the unsorted array(in this case the top array is sorted). Worst case, the unsorted array would be the sorted array except reversed. Therefore, you would compare 1,4 followed by 1,3 followed by ... etc. You would then compare 2,4 then 2,3 etc.
Therefore, you would end up with O(n*m)

Is this correct?

Comment: You should be suspicious of this result because it's the same as if *both* arrays were unsorted.  Hint: How long does it take to look up an item in a sorted list?

Comment: Using binary search, it should be log(n) time. Does that mean it should be O(log(n)*m) time?

Comment: By taking each element in the unsorted array and looking for it in the sorted array! This makes sense.

Comment: Good!  Problem solved. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! It helps that I was able to figure it out myself as well, so I could fully understand it and get that sense of satisfaction. Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome :)  I also prefer to get a hint rather than a full answer on a problem like this.

Comment: You asked for the _fastest_ algorithm. Your algorithm doesn't take advantage of the fact that one array is already sorted.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: That's a solution better than O (nm). Likely not the fastest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest solution puts the elements of the smaller array into a hash table, then looks up the elements of the larger table. In practice this is O (max (n, m)).

Comment: This is the *actual* fastest solution.

Comment: The time complexity is O(m+n) (which is, as you say, faster than my suggestion).   The space complexity is O(min(n, m)).

Comment: Looks like you are correct. Green check for you! Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1):

Credits to j_random_hacker,

It should be O(log(n)*m)
You can look up each item from the unsorted array in the sorted array using binary search, which is log(n) time. For each item in the unsorted array, this should be O(log(n)*m) time.